# Timer can't use all parameters from main function

Tags: java

its my first time using the timer method in Java and it doesn't seem as straightforward as other timer methods I used in the past in other languages (ie C++)

I want to have a function that calls every second or so while I have other things happening in the background in multiple other threads.

I came across a method that seems to work inside the main function as long as the variables referenced inside the timer function are defined as final.  One variable I can not have as final and so I'm having trouble referencing this inside the timer function.

So, my question is, is this a good way to use the timer method?  Keeping in mind there are a large number of items I may need to use inside the timer function?  Or is it a matter of using a different method to access the single variable reference giving me grief? The solution could be simple, apologies if it is, its been a long day and I'm on a deadline making my brain shut down on occasion.

Thanks for any help/suggestions etc

Here is what my code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    String StringThatWillBeChangingOften = "";
    final String finalString = "abc";

    try{

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            String s = StringThatWillBeChangingOften;  //ERROR ON THIS LINE

            public void run() {
                //Referencing other variables from main works fine as long they are defined as final
                //ie finalString works fine
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);

    //Catch...
    }
}
```

Comment: When the run() method of your Timer is executed, do you want it to use the value of `StringThatWillBeChangingOften` that it had when creating the timer, or do you want it to use the value of `StringThatWillBeChangingOften` that it has now?

Comment: It can be treated as a pass by reference - no changes will be made to it inside Timer

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: The value it has now

Comment: Then Didi's answer is your answer, and you definitely need synchronization, since the main thread modifies the value while the timer thread reads it.

Comment: I'm taking a copy of the variable and using the copy inside the timer function, that suits my purposes in my implementation.  Sync is not needed.  Thanks heaps for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: If you're using a static field, you're not taking a copy. You're using the same variable as the main thread. You just told that you wanted the value it has now, and not the value it had when started the Timer, so you can't use a copy. I find it strange that you're so confident about synchronization if you can't understand how to solve your simple original problem. Believe me: you need synchronization. Your field should at least be declared as volatile.

Comment: I tested it and it worked the way I wanted, it didnt keep the static value initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two solutions for your problem. First, you create a class `StringWrapper` that simply wraps a `String` and provides a getter and a setter. Thus, you would be able to declare it final and change its value during the execution.

Another solution, which is the one I would recommand, is to declare your `String` as an attribute (static or not depending on its role, but in your current code it could only be static), then the `final` keyword would not be required anymore.

**EDIT :**

As *JB Nizet* observed it, note that if this variable is to be used concurrently by multiple threads, synchronization is required. In the first case you would do this in the getter/setter code, in the second case you should not access directly the attribute and implement thread-safe getter and setter.

Comment: In both cases, synchronization is needed to access the field, since one thread changes its value while another one reads it.

Comment: Surely, but it is a separate question, isn't it ?

Comment: Sort of. But it's worth mentioning, IMO.

Comment: It won't need synchronising in my case

Comment: @DenizC yes, it will. Why wouldn't it? Do you run the code on a custom-made Java VM that allows accessing shared state without synchonization and without any visibility issue?

Comment: It would be better with it but it is not essential in my case

Comment: So, it's alright for your Timer to use the value that the string had 1 hour ago, right?

Comment: For my purposes, yes.  On each run override inside the timer the current value of that variable is read and used in a quick loop that sends the data by UDP to clients that are prepared for loss of data and don't particularly care how old the data is as long as it is within a few seconds of accuracy.  Hence, sync could be used but not essential.

Comment: *as long as it is within a few seconds of accuracy*: the only way to guarantee that is to use synchronization. Without it, your timer thread might see the same initial value eternally, even if the main thread changed it 1,000 times since then. Because without synchronization, you have no guarantee that what has been written by one thread is visible in another thread.

Comment: Its for a chat program, no one can type that fast so that the value wont change a few times within a second and even if they did it wont matter as the client will only display changed items coming from UDP